# Service Fabric services debugging issues

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have 2 Service Fabric services, which I need to debug. Those services communicate with each other.
I am using:

```
VS 2017(update 7),  
.NET Framework 4.6.1,
Azure SDK 2.9.5.3,  
Service Fabric Tools 2.0.20180124.2,  
Service Fabric 6.1.456.9494,
Service Fabric SDK 3.0.456.9494
```

Everything was going alright, but at some point I've started to get following errors, when I try to start debugging 2nd service. 
I don't understand why I am getting those errors.(Google produces absolutely nothing on those errors) Here they are:

> 1st error: Error  MSB4064 The "ProjectReferencesWithConfiguration"
>   parameter is not supported by the "GetServiceProjectReferences" task.
>   Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public
>   instance
>   property. \packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.5\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets   95
>
> 2nd error:Error   MSB4063 The "GetServiceProjectReferences" task could
>   not be initialized with its input parameters.
>     \packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.5\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets   94

Here is complete scenario:

1. One of the services(does not matter which one) in one copy of VS has started successfully without errors.
2. I've trying to start 2nd service in another copy of VS. And during this attempt I'm getting errors I've mentioned above.

To remedy the situation I have to close offending copy of the VS and open ServiceFabric service project in new VS copy and after that service will start successfully.
Unfortunately all that dancing are getting quite annoying because it's taking up A LOT OF time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here. Same VS, framework 4.7.1, same SF (6.1.456). My scenario is that I have service A in app M, which I package as a Nuget package using SFNuget, and pull it into app N as a service package. If I deploy either app M or app N, I get this error until I re-open VS. Your scenario is more general if it's just two distinct services. What do you mean by "communicate with each other" ?

Comment: @Lyall There exchange messages on servicebus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like updating Service Fabric SDK to 467 version did the the trick.
I've been working all day today and didn't see pesky error messages during services start up. Now I have in Control Panel\Programs and Features following lines:

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric 6.1.467.9494
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 6.1.467.9494

Comment: Currently i am using Service Fabric SDK 3.0.456.9494. How to update Service Fabric SDK to 467 version ?

Comment: @prasanthi You could use Web Platform installer to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by upgrading Nuget package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild from version 1.6.4 to 1.6.5

After that also had to manually change 1.6.4 to 1.6.5 in the .sfproj file, as Nuget package manager did not do that automatically.

Comment: From what I've found - this is the best answer. In my case (since there are new updates) it was a move to 1.6.7 with the manual update to the .sfproj file - and it works well now :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading Visual Studio to version 15.6.4 (can't remember what my previous version was). Tried altumano's solution of updating Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild and ran into other errors.

Solution that appears to have worked for me is to upgrade Visual Studio again to version 15.6.6. I still plan to update Service Fabric SDK to a more recent version, but so far this Visual Studio update alone has solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading Visual Studio to version 15.6.7 and Service Fabric SDK to version 3.1.269 seems to work.